# ¿Por qué el JInternalFrame se dibuja mal cuando lo abro en un JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un JDesktopPane con un barra de menú donde hay un item que cuando lo pulsas te abre un JInternalFrame, hasta aquí todo correcto. El problema viene cuando abre esa ventana, porque no es capaz de mostrarla bien y la dibuja a cachos.
[image: Así se ve nada más darel a abrir]

Se carga más o menos cuando pasas el ratón por encima de las pestañas.
[image: Esta es la ventana después de pasar el ratón por las pestañas]

No se si hay alguna forma de arreglar esto. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

El código entero no cabe aquí pero os dejo el enlace a GitHub: https://github.com/pablo5795/ProyrctoFinal

Comment: agrega tu código para ayudarte mas facíl

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la propiedad `opaque` del contenedor raiz a `TRUE`.